# Encrypted boot partition is automatically decrypted at boot

Tags: linux, debian, luks

I have a question concerning the behavior of decrypting encrypted devices at startup.

I am using two different installations of Debian 11. One is a headless server installation without any GUI and the other is a normal desktop installation with a LXQt as Desktop Environment. Both systems have encrypted root and swap partitions and also a encrypted boot partition. On the server root lies on a LVM volume on top of the encrypted partition.

Now, when I boot the server at first grub asks me to unlock the boot partition. Then during initramfs stage I am asked to unlock the root partition and after this during init phase to unlock the boot partition again, of course. But when I boot the desktop installation everything until unlocking the root partition is the same but then I am not asked for the password for the boot partition in the init stage again. Instead the boot is encrypted automatically and mounts without any input.

This is what I don't understand. What's the difference, so that the password is not needed a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Your desktop might be using an additional keyfile. When you unlock the root partition this keyfile can be then used to unlock the boot partition without asking for a password. I personally dislike having unencrypted keys laying around on the file system while the host is running, but it can save typing when starting up.

An encrypted partition has multiple slots that can be filled with passwords or keyfiles, which allows potentially for multiple users to have access to the system without sharing passwords. The keyfiles could be used to enable access by inserting a USB drive or a smartcard.

Comment: Yes, a keyfile was also something I would have expected but I never configured one and in /etc/crypttab the corresponding entry for boot does not contain a keyfile or a keyscript or anything else, simply luks. And dumping the LUKS header shows that there is only one keyslot for a passphrase. My guess was that in initramfs stage the password is stored to kernel userspace keyring and asked for at later time for boot. But I can't find any clue for that because manually requesting the keyring only shows, it is empty. Maybe it is deleted after usage but that's really only an assumption.

Comment: You will not find remains of the initrd environment in your shell after booting was finished. You need to interrupt the booting process and land into the initrd environment itself. Then you can look around and see what is happening. The initrd is actually controlled by scripts in plain text so you can analyze, modify and debug them if needed (consult your initrd making program on how to patch the initrd scripts). Look [here](https://wiki.debian.org/InitramfsDebug) on how to stop in the rescue shell.

Comment: You can use a kernel parameter `break=something` to stop in the rescue shell, where `something` can be something of: top, modules, premount, mount, mountroot, bottom, init.

Comment: I know that I don't find any remains of the initramfs after the real root filesystem ist mounted but the kernel keyrings are not saved in initramfs or on disk so that they are also available after initramfs stage. Interrupting the boot process is something I have already done. There I logged the mount of the encrypted root device but in the log file I haven't discovered anything that would explain what I described.  The weird thing is if I interrupt the boot process and get a rescue shell, after continuing the boot process I am asked for the password of the boot partition.

Comment: What does `cryptsetup luksDump` say? Do you have only one slot filled with password, or is a keyslot also filled?

Comment: No, there is only one keyslot for a passphrase, no other slot is used.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I don't know how could this have been implemented. Possibly with a kernel keyring as you mentioned.